# Fantasy novel featuring a female lead who is a medic in the US army

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel about 7-8 years back. The female lead is a US army medic who after a blast wakes up in a different world which has a different spoken language than the Earth. On waking up she comes across riders who take her to an inn. She later discovers that she was taken by her mother to Earth to keep her safe. She becomes part of the rebellion against the present rulers.